# Connecting the Dots ggplot2 qplot

Tags: r

I'm working on a homework assignment for the Coursera Exploratory Data Analysis class, and this code creates the following image:

```
qplot(year, Emissions, data=Baltimore_Data, 
      stat='summary', fun.y='sum', facets=.~type)
```

[image: Plot made with qplot/ggplot2]

I am trying to connect the dots, and I've been trying things like:

```
+ geom_line()
```

and

```
+ geom_polygon()
```

and lots of other things to no avail. For what it's worth, I already met the intent without the lines, I just wanted to make it prettier and it bothers me that I can't figure it out!

Comment: http://rpubs.com/amyherml/Coursera_Emission

Comment: @nongkrong; not in this case i dont think. By adding `geom_line` or `geom_path` afterwards will create the line/path on the `x=year` and `y=Emissions` scale, however, the points have been plot on the `y=sum(Emissions)` scale. Hence, may not correspond. Probably easiest to aggregate the data before hand, similar to the linked answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to aggregate outside of ggplot or use `stat_summary` twice (which is somewhat wasteful for bigger datasets):

```
ggplot(Baltimore_Data, aes(x = year, y= Emissions)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = sum, geom = "point") +
  stat_summary(fun.y = sum, geom = "line") +
  facet_grid(. ~ type)
```

(Not tested because there is no reproducible example in the question.)

Comment: Thanks, that worked exactly like I wanted it to. Great job even though I couldn't figure out how to neatly give you a reproducible data set!!